# DFS is not enabled or the system is not a data node.?

Tags: time-series, dolphindb

When the following scripts are executed in the DolphinDB GUI, an exception

```
DFS is not enabled or the system is not a data node.
```

is thrown, and I confirm that the configuration item `enableDFS = 1'has been set.

```
DB = database("dfs://dolphindb_compo")
tb = DB.loadTable("tb1")
```

Comment: if you start DolpinDB by docker-compose, this port could be 8900, please check the config named `controller.cfg`

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely you submitted the script to an agent or a controller instead of a data node.